# Broken packages while installing cuda-drivers in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nvidia, package-management, cuda

I am trying to install cuda on Ubuntu 14.04, I posted a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598607/package-dependency-problem-while-installing-cuda-on-ubuntu-14-04/598616#598616) , and tried to install cuda via aptitude. I eventually got an error message of broken packages (and now I have a red sign on the upper bar of the Unity panel, alarming me of unmet dependencies.

This is part of the message I got trying to fix this problem using Synaptic package manager:

```
E: /var/cuda-repo-7-0-local/./nvidia-opencl-icd-346_346.46-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb: trying to overwrite '/etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd', which is also in package nvidia-opencl-icd-331 331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4
```

And the full error message is [here](http://dpaste.com/2VDM152).

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release notes suggest to remove the nvidia-opencl-icd-* package and then try the upgrade again.

See, http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#axzz3VF4pSfRr under known issues.