# Can't Install Cuda on Ubuntu 14.04 Because of Package Conflicts

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management, cuda

I believe I have the same problem as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598607/package-dependency-problem-while-installing-cuda-on-ubuntu-14-04) thread, but I have tried the steps listed, and I am not able to solve the problem.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 64bit on a custom desktop with 4GB DDR3 ram, Intel i3 processor at 3.3 GHz, and an GeForce GTX 950 using the nvidia driver 352.63 under the additional drivers tab in Software & Updates. I am trying to install cuda using [this](http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing/cuda-installation/cuda7.5-ubuntu) method.

This is the terminal output when trying to install cuda via apt:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cuda  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
 cuda : Depends: cuda-7-5 (= 7.5-18) but it is not going to be installed  
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is what I get using Aptitude:

```
$ sudo aptitude install cuda  
The following NEW packages will be installed:  
  cuda cuda-7-5{a} cuda-command-line-tools-7-5{a} cuda-core-7-5{a}   
  cuda-cublas-7-5{a} cuda-cublas-dev-7-5{a} cuda-cudart-7-5{a}   
  cuda-cudart-dev-7-5{a} cuda-cufft-7-5{a} cuda-cufft-dev-7-5{a}   
  cuda-curand-7-5{a} cuda-curand-dev-7-5{a} cuda-cusolver-7-5{a}   
  cuda-cusolver-dev-7-5{a} cuda-cusparse-7-5{a} cuda-cusparse-dev-7-5{a}   
  cuda-documentation-7-5{a} cuda-driver-dev-7-5{a} cuda-drivers{a}   
  cuda-license-7-5{a} cuda-misc-headers-7-5{a} cuda-npp-7-5{a}   
  cuda-npp-dev-7-5{a} cuda-nvrtc-7-5{a} cuda-nvrtc-dev-7-5{a} cuda-runtime-7-5{a}   
  cuda-samples-7-5{a} cuda-toolkit-7-5{a} cuda-visual-tools-7-5{a}   
  freeglut3-dev{a} libdrm-dev{ab} libgl1-mesa-dev{a}   
  libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic{ab} libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic{ab}   
  libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic{ab} libglu1-mesa-dev{a} libllvm3.5{a}   
  libx11-xcb-dev{a} libxcb-dri2-0-dev{a} libxcb-dri3-dev{a} libxcb-glx0-dev{a}   
  libxcb-present-dev{a} libxcb-randr0-dev{a} libxcb-shape0-dev{a}   
  libxcb-sync-dev{a} libxcb-xfixes0-dev{a} libxmu-dev{a} libxmu-headers{a}   
  libxshmfence-dev{a} libxt-dev{a} libxxf86vm-dev{a} mesa-common-dev{a}   
  nvidia-352-dev{a} nvidia-352-uvm{a} nvidia-modprobe{a} x11proto-dri2-dev{a}   
  x11proto-gl-dev{a} x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev{a}   
0 packages upgraded, 58 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.  
Need to get 12.5 MB/1,049 MB of archives. After unpacking 1,735 MB will be used.  
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-dri but   11.0.4~git20151026+11.0.ec14e6f8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty is installed.  
 libdrm-dev : Depends: libdrm2 (= 2.4.64-1~ubuntu14.04.1) but 2.4.65+git20151026.c745e541-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty is installed.  
              Depends: libdrm-intel1 (= 2.4.64-1~ubuntu14.04.1) but 2.4.65+git20151026.c745e541-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty is installed.  
              Depends: libdrm-radeon1 (= 2.4.64-1~ubuntu14.04.1) but 2.4.65+git20151026.c745e541-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty is installed.  
              Depends: libdrm-nouveau2 (= 2.4.64-1~ubuntu14.04.1) but 2.4.65+git20151026.c745e541-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty is installed.  
              Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1 (= 2.4.64-1~ubuntu14.04.1) but 2.4.65+git20151026.c745e541-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty is installed.  
 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libgl1 which is a virtual package.  
                              Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-glx but 11.0.4~git20151026+11.0.ec14e6f8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty is installed.  
 libgl1-mesa-glx : Conflicts: libgl1 which is a virtual package.  
 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libglapi-mesa but 11.0.4~git20151026+11.0.ec14e6f8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty is installed.  
 xserver-xorg : Conflicts: xorg-renamed-package which is a virtual package.  
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:  

Keep the following packages at their current version:  
1)      cuda [Not Installed]                                 
2)      cuda-7-5 [Not Installed]                             
3)      cuda-documentation-7-5 [Not Installed]               
4)      cuda-samples-7-5 [Not Installed]                     
5)      cuda-toolkit-7-5 [Not Installed]                     
6)      freeglut3-dev [Not Installed]                        
7)      libdrm-dev [Not Installed]                           
8)      libgl1-mesa-dev [Not Installed]                      
9)      libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic [Not Installed]           
10)     libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic [Not Installed]           
11)     libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic [Not Installed]             
12)     libglu1-mesa-dev [Not Installed]                     
13)     mesa-common-dev [Not Installed]                      



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y    
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.    
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.    
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

I am not a complete Linux geek, but I am fairly comfortable in the terminal and am willing to learn. This is not a very urgent problem, but any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried removing the conflicting package and then running it again?

Comment: Sudo apt-get remove libgl-mesa-glx-lts-utopic gives me: unable to locate package. And sudo apt-get remove libgl1 gives me: virtual packages cant be removed

Comment: How about libgl1-mesa-dri?

Comment: I was having some other problems (maybe related) so I am doing a clean install. I will try to install cuda again after I configure my new OS.

Comment: It installed like a dream after I reinstalled the operating system.