# Ubunt 16.04 Cuda 8.deb unmet dependencies error

Tags: dependencies, deb, cuda

```
$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-cublas-performance-update_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install cuda-8-0
```

I installed cuda 8 by using .deb file and above commands on several ubunt machines.
But when I tried this on my new GPU server machine, I encountered the following error. (My Ubuntu version is 16.04.2 LTS)

```
gpu01@MLILAB:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install cuda-8-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-8-0 : Depends: cuda-toolkit-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there anyone who suffered the same error or know how to solve it?

I need your help :)

(I must use CUDA 8 instead of other version T.T)

Comment: I solve it by referring https://askubuntu.com/questions/598607/package-dependency-problem-while-installing-cuda-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install aptitude
$ sudo aptitude install cuda-8-0 -y
(this instruction installed every required dependencies) great!!

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have already succeeded. I got the same error and eventually succeeded.

What I did following the commands you cited:

I removed the two packages that I have just installed:

```
# apt list --installed | grep -i cuda
cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-cublas-performance-update/now 8.0.61-1 amd64 [installed,local]
cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2/now 8.0.61-1 amd64 [installed,local]

# apt remove cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2
# apt remove cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-cublas-performance-update
# rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda-8-0-local-ga2.list
# rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda-8-0-local-cublas-performance-update.list
```

In the [CUDA Toolkit 8.0 - Feb 2017](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-80-ga2-download-archive) download web page, this time, I choose Linux -> x86_64 -> Ubuntu -> 16.04 -> deb (network), instead of deb (local). Then installed the downloaded deb package (2.6K byte)

```
# dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb
# apt list --installed | grep -i cuda
cuda-repo-ubuntu1604/now 8.0.61-1 amd64 [installed,local]
```

It installed a file pointing to the CUDA network repository.

```
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list
deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64 /
```

Now, tried again to install CUDA 8:

```
# aptitude install cuda-8-0
...

# apt list --installed | grep -i cuda
cuda-8-0/unknown,now 8.0.61-1 amd64 [installed]
cuda-command-line-tools-8-0/unknown,now 8.0.61-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-core-8-0/unknown,now 8.0.61-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
...
```

Installation of CUDA Toolkit 8.0 has succeeded without any dependency error.

**What I have learned**

It seems that installation of `cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb` sets up a CUDA local repository in the directory `/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda-8-0-local-ga2.list` points to that repository. `apt-get install cuda` will then take deb packages from that directory. I guess there seems somewhat missing packages related to the dependency requirements in that repository. In contrast, the CUDA network repository might have more packages compared to such a local repository, which will solve dependency requirements. That is just my guess, though.

As of today, December 2017, `aptitude install cuda` will install cuda-9.1, so we will need to explicitly specify cuda-8-0 if we use CUDA 8.

Just additional information. I mistakenly removed a signing key for the CUDA repository and faced an error during `apt-get update`.

```
# apt-key del 7FA2AF80
# apt-get update
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F60F4B3D7FA2AF80
  ...
```

Reinstalling it has solved this small problem.

```
# wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
# apt-key add 7fa2af80.pub
# apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
```

I hope this post help those who encounter the same errors. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure,  @BruceYo!